# Does Xamarin C# apps work without requiring Mono compiler?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, apk

I mean, if I send an apk developed in Xamarin to my friend to install, does he needs Mono framework on his phone or it will install and run without any 3rd party application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> On Android, Xamarin ships a fully functional implementation of the .NET runtime, called Mono, bundled with your app so that your code executes with all of the power of C# and .NET, including JIT-compilation, memory management, reflection, and the .NET base class libraries.

[Source](http://xamarin.com/faq)

Yes, that should work fine without requiring Mono to be installed on your friend's device.

Comment: Thank you, tagged as answer!